# Crawling a Facebook fanpage 

Tags: facebook, web-crawler

I want to cral a facebook fanpage to get the details of all the members who are fans of that page. I there any function in the face book API which will help me. Or is ther any other way I can do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try DineJS, a programmable crawler:

http://code.google.com/p/dinejs/wiki/Samples

Answer (score 1):

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) is also a nice framework for writing custom crawlers.